# How to easily save data on a remote location

Tags: android, cloud

I am creating an application used for testing purposes.

I would like to store all the test results created by the users in some kind of remote location, so that they can be easily accessed and examined.

I do not need a complex solution, only save the records somewhere so that they can be accessed by the admim.

Please what could be the simplest approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use android [remote data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw) options using http client or url connection.

You can see this answer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289447/403255

Comment: Thanks Vinothkumar, but for that I would need to create a web host to store the data. I was looking for something possible more simple.

Comment: You can use any freely available file servers. You can try Google Drive, Dropbox also